# Windows Server 2008/Vista- check which server roles installed

Tags: wix, windows-server-2008, wix3.5, wix3, windows-administration

I know that `serverManagerCmd.exe -query <foo.xml>` will output list of all roles + features in xml format. However, I do not have the ability to parse this easily as I am writing WiX code.

So is there a command which returns different codes depending on whether the server role you specify are installed or not?

**Background:**
I am trying to write a WiX installer which checks if a server role is installed and only runs a command to install if not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Win32_ServerFeature Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) class may be of use to you. See also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280268(VS.85).aspx.

I've never used WiX, but I'm assuming it supports WMI.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a built in WiX element to allow you to do this.

The best thing to do is probably to write a Custom Action, which allows you to write the logic in C# or VB using all the normal .NET functionality. You can then call that Custom Action from the installer in order to deal with the roles.